# Firebase push notifications suddenly stooped working in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My flutter app was receiving firebase push notifications properly on both `iOS` and `Android` but today, out of the blue, it stopped receiving push notifications though response for sending push through `cURL` returns a success message. I am following [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage)
guide for implementing firebase push notifications. App is not receiving push in both foreground and background mode.

Following is my `function` which was working just fine few hours ago.

```
  Future<void> _configureFcm() async {
    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    _userLoginModel = await Others.getUserLoginStatus();
    _subscription = _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) async {
      _firebaseHelper.saveTokenToFirebaseServer(
        token,
        _userLoginModel.userId,
        widget._userType,
      );
    });
    _firebaseHelper.saveTokenToFirebaseServer(
      await _firebaseMessaging.getToken(),
      _userLoginModel.userId,
      widget._userType,
    );
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('received notification');
     });
  }
```

**FAQs**

1. Was this function working before? ==> Yes, it was
2. Did you make any changes to any of the code related to notifications? ==> No, in fact I did not make any change in my code at all
3. Did you try real device? ==> Yes, I tried real `Android` and `iOS` devices, they were working fine before but not anymore
4. Did you check your connection to Firebase App? ==> Yes I did, other services like Cloud Firestore and Auth is working just fine
5. Did you try `flutter clean`? ==> Yes, I did

Comment: Run clutter clean and then run again

Comment: Tried it as well, no luck

Comment: Are you using Cloud Functions?

Comment: Did you try sending messages from the firebase console ?

Comment: I tried firebase console, cURL, none worked

Comment: @intraector, I am using http API for FCM

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @AhmedElsayed I simply waited for a while and then they started working again, not sure why but they did on their own

Comment: I solved it also ,I found that the Firebase token of the user was null .